# The print button doesn't appear in firefox

Tags: firefox, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

Q:

Why the `print button` doesn't appear in report viewer in the case of browsing through the `Firefox` ?

How to show this button in this browser to print my report?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the print button is an Active-X control and Active-X controls work only with Internet explorer

For the rest of browsers export to pdf or excel and print from the application

In case the entire report renders in one page, you can use the browser print button to print the report