# microsoft report viewer print button missing in mozilla

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application and using using rdlc reports. when i preview report in report viewer print button missing in mozilla, it is displayed in IE but prb with mozilla. can you please let me know any plugin or something for mozilla.

Comment: Refresh your page by pressing. Ctrl + R

Comment: report disappears..blank page remains if i press Ctrl+R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print button is an ActiveX control and works in IE 9 (or earlier) only. You can find solution in those topics:

[The print button doesn't appear in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385923/the-print-button-doesnt-appear-in-firefox)

[SQL Reporting Services - Print Button not shown in Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951009/sql-reporting-services-print-button-not-shown-in-mozilla)

Comment: is there any plugin for this ?

Comment: Check the second link, it has a jQuery-based solution. Or export report to PDF and print it from Acrobat Reader.