# Print Button Not displayed in Firefox in Report Viewer Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, .net-4.0, reportviewer

I'm working on a web application with VS 2010 and I'm developing its report Microsoft Report viewer, My big problem is I want to print the report in "Mozilla Firefox browser" - and the print button not displayed on Firefox.

Is there any funcationality makes me able to print my report in Firefox???

I need your help Professors :) ... There is No Problem in Programming :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The print button is an Active X control, only works on Internet explorer.

Check this [article](http://www.codicode.com/art/cross_browser_printing_with_asp_net_reportviewer.aspx) i wrote explaining how to add client side printing (on all browsers) for ms reportviewer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhpas this may help

[The print button doesn't appear in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385923/the-print-button-doesnt-appear-in-firefox)

check this as well

[SQL Reporting Services - Print Button not shown in Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951009/sql-reporting-services-print-button-not-shown-in-mozilla)